# Make y.tab.h of YACC include <string>

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I am making a parser for C language using YACC and LEX.

When I was compilng my parser by following command:
`g++ lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o parser -lfl`.
It saids that my y.tab.h, which is included by lex.yy.c, did not include `<string>`. So that the `%union` cannot use the type. For specific, this is my `y.tab.h`

```
// This is y.tab.h
typedef union YYSTYPE {
    int ival;
    double dval;
    string sval;
} YYSTYPE;
```

and the `string sval;` cannot be parse by g++. How can I make my `y.tab.h` automatically include `<string>` when it generated by `byacc -d parser.y`

Comment: Unlike GNU Bison, it seems that Berkeley Yacc (`byacc`) doesn't have any support for C++. And that includes putting non-POD classes in the union, which isn't possible without a union constructor. So what you want to do is simply not possible with the Yacc-implementation you have chosen.

Comment: I would have thought this was possible with `%{...}`. C++ isn't the issue here: the same would apply to any structure defined in any external .h/library. And if it isn't possible with `%{...}`, you can always `#include` whatever you need before `#include y.tab.h` in every affected source file

Comment: @user207421 The problem is that, I do have included the `<string>` in the `%{...%}` area of my `scanner.l`.
But g++ cannot parse `y.tab.h` without knowing what `string` is

Comment: So do what I said, `#include <string>` before `#include "y.atb.h"`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What if I compile it by `bision -d parser.y`

Comment: @user207421 Yes, I did.  The problem now is that `union member 'YYSTYPE::sval' with non-trivial "string"`
and then this cause another error:`'YYSTYPE::YYSTYPE()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed`